# change header image on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Right now I have one fixed image in the header. I want to say that when half the page was scrolled, the picture in the header changed to another.

Do I need to use javascript for this or can I get by with css?

```css
body {
    height:1200px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
}
.header_nav {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#666;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    color:#fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_nav"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/200/200.jpg?hmac=Q1gdvE6ZPZUX3nXkxvmzuc12eKVZ9XVEmSH3nCJ2OOo"></div>
```

Comment: If I got it right, you want to make available options to be dependent on the model opening/closing hours. 
In such case consider splitting form on several steps and loading html  for these steps dynamically via ajax. For example:

1) user selects institution

2) here you make ajax-call to server - send institution id and get html like "<select>...all available slots for concrete model...</select>"

3) user selects date and time slot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scrollTop()` and specify when exactly the image will change

```js
$(function () { 
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) { 
            $('.header_nav img').attr('src','https://i.picsum.photos/id/912/200/200.jpg?hmac=tYYyMFni6bya5yEVkwmmFekjWGedHVByLtPI5q1lcyw');
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 600) { 
            $('.header_nav img').attr('src','https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/200/200.jpg?hmac=Q1gdvE6ZPZUX3nXkxvmzuc12eKVZ9XVEmSH3nCJ2OOo');
        }
    })
});
```

```css
body {
    height:1200px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
}
.header_nav {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#666;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    color:#fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header_nav"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/200/200.jpg?hmac=Q1gdvE6ZPZUX3nXkxvmzuc12eKVZ9XVEmSH3nCJ2OOo"></div>
```